# How to Solve Functional Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, functional

I tried to solve this equation numerically.

```
eqnEx = x''[t] + x[2 t] == 0;
NDSolve[{eqnEx, x[1] == 10, x'[1] == 0}, x[t], {t, 1, 10}]
```

Two important character of the equation are that function variable is 2t and initial condition is given at t=1 .

After Calculation, Mathematica gives this error message

```
NDSolve : The method currently implemented for delay differential equations does not support delays that depend directly on the time variable or dependent variables
```

After google, I find these kind of equation are called Functional Differential Equation and I could not obtain how to solve it. Is there a way to solve these kind of equation numerically?

Comment: If you set $t=1$ the system remains ill defined since `x[2]` is not known?

Comment: **Maple 2021** Can solve this with numerics.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  Please provide the answer from Maple?

Comment: @chris yes x[2] is not known.
Edit : Is the problem solvable if x[2] provided?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by Daniel Lichtblau, the functional differential equation in the question can be converted to a delay differential equation as follows.  With

```
rult = t -> 2^-s;
```

`2 t` becomes `2^-(s-1)`, as desired.  To proceed,

```
ruls = Simplify[Solve[Equal @@ rult, s] /. C[1] -> 0, t > 0][[1, 1]]
(* s -> -Log[t]/Log[2] *)
```

and the range of integration `{t, 1, 10}` becomes `{s, smin, 0}` with

```
smin = s /. ruls /. t -> 10
(* -Log[10]/Log[2] *)
```

The differential equation and boundary conditions themselves are transformed by

```
D[x[s /. ruls], t] /. Reverse[ruls] /. rult
(* -2^s x'[s]/Log[2] *)
Simplify[D[x[s /. ruls], t, t] /. Reverse[ruls] /. rult]
(* 4^s (Log[2] x'[s] + x''[s])/Log[2]^2 *)
eq = Simplify[(2^-s Log[2])^2 (%78 + x[s - 1])]
(* -4^-s Log[2]^2 x[-1 + s] + Log[2] x'[s] + x''[s] *)
```

and

```
x[0] == 10;
x'[0] == 0;
```

Unfortunately, the integration must begin at `smin`, as required by `DSolve`, and the boundary conditions are at `0`. The problem can be solved, nonetheless.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == 0, x[s /; s < smin] == xp + (s - smin) xpp, 
    x'[s /; s < smin] == xpp}, {x[0], x'[0]}, {s, smin, 0}, {xp, xpp}];
Values[FindRoot[sol[xp0, xpp0] - {10, 0}, {xp0, 1}, {xpp0, 1}, Evaluated -> False]]
(* {-0.788537, -0.990015} *)
```

effectively transferring the boundary conditions to `smin`.  Finally,

```
NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, x[s /; s < smin] == #1 + (s - smin) #2, 
    x'[s /; s < smin] == #2}, x[s], {s, smin, 0}] & @@ %;
ParametricPlot[{t /. rult, %}, {s, smin, 0}, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, PlotRange -> All, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

I close with the important caveat that the solution depends, as it must, on the assumed form of `x[s]` in the range `{s, smin - 1, smin}`, which is not specified in the question.  Consequently, I made the simplest reasonable assumption, that `x[s]` varies linearly in that range.

Addendum: Extended integration range

A small amount of experimentation reveals that decreasing `smin` to `-6` yields a solution insensitive to details of `x[s]` for s less than `smin` (i.e., for large `t`).  Superimposing the two curves above shows very good, although not perfect, agreement over `{t, 1, 10}`.

[image]

Comment: After considerate review of your solution, I think Equaiton `(* -4^-s Log[2]^2 x[-1 + s] + Log[2] x'[s] + x''[s] *)` should be  `(* 4^-s Log[2]^2 x[-1 + s] + Log[2] x'[s] + x''[s] *)` not a minus sign. Then the solution will be same as mine. Still, your solution is so helpful and I appreciate it.

Comment: @OneMoreLovely  You are correct.  I miscopied the original equation.  I shall correct the answer now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@bbgodfrey I tried to follow your method to solve the equation. The difference is that we choose different transformation of variables.

Step 1) make Delay Diff Eq using substitution by `t = Exp[-s]`

```
`testfun = x''[t] + x[2 t]
 testfun /. {x -> (x[-Log[#]] &)} /. t -> Exp[-s] // PowerExpand`
```

Step 2) The substitution makes `x[s=0]=10` and `x'[s=0]=0`are not the initial condition as you pointed out. The actual initial condition should be given at `s=-Log[10]`. I followed same logic as you. only difference is the result `{-0.788537, -1.42829}` not `{28.1156, 49.9555}` because of different parametrization.

Step 3) solve Delay Diff Eq with linear-assumed boundary condition.

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, x[s /; s < smin] == -0.7885374724851758 + (s - 
    smin) (-1.428289649546688`), 
x'[s /; s < smin] == -1.428289649546688`}, x, {s, smin, 0}]
```

Step 4) change variable s to t and plot. it looks like something different comparing your answer.

```
ParametricPlot[{t /. t -> Exp[-s], sol2[s]}, {s, smin, 0}, 
AxesLabel -> {t, x}, PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black},
ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True]
```

Step 5) Check whether or not the obtained solution follows Diff equation in my question. We have checked with x[s] and Equation modified in Step 1. `x[s - Log[2]] + E^(2 s) Derivative[1][x][s] +  E^(2 s) (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s]==0`

[image: Result]

```
Derivative[2][sol2][-1] + Derivative[1][sol2][-1] + Exp[-2 (-1)] sol2[-1 - Log[2]] // N (* 4.48826*10^-8 *)
Derivative[2][sol2][-1.2] + Derivative[1][sol2][-1.2] + Exp[-2 (-1.2)] sol2[-1.2 - Log[2]] // N (* -2.452*10^-6 *)
Derivative[2][sol2][-1.6] + Derivative[1][sol2][-1.6] + Exp[-2 (-1.6)] sol2[-1.6 - Log[2]] // N (* -0.0000118291 *)
```

It seems our solution is consistent with the equation. I really concern why there is difference between our two solutions. Thanks a lot @bbgodfrey.

Answer (score 2):

I have only numeric solution by [Maple 2021](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/new_features/).

Maple code:

```
sol := dsolve([diff(x(t), t $ 2) + x(2*t) = 0, x(1) = 10, D(x)(1) = 0], numeric, delaymax = 1):
plots[odeplot](sol, [[t, x(t)], [t, D(x)(t)]], t = -1 .. 10, legend = [typeset(x(t)), typeset(diff(x(t), t))])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution from Maple.  I had expected that values of `x` for `t` outside `{1, 10}` would be required as input, as they are for delay differential equations.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk. I checked your answer and comment carefully. Your comment is totally right. Since the second derivative in [7,10] is zero which can not be the right solution of this equation. Thank you again for giving me a clue to use Maple solving delay differential equation.  Is there any method to solve the question with Mathematica or debug with Maple code? I guess the issue might come from the definition of delaymax.

Comment: @OneMoreLovely Yours is not a delay differential equation, and `NDSolve` has no options for solving it. I do have some ideas but will not have time to pursue them until the end of the week. Am I correct in assuming that `x[t]` must be infinitely differentiable, for `Infinity > t > 1`?

Comment: @bgodfrey It can be transformed to a DDE via `t=log(s)`. Problem is, one can only go downward in time. Something like this, if I did the algebra correctly (unlikely): `NDSolveValue[{x[s + 1] == Log[2]^2*(x'[s]*s + x''[s]*s^2), x[2] == 10,
   x'[2] == 1/10}, {x[s]}, {s, 2, .1}]`.

Comment: Great suggestion, although `t -> 2^-s` seems like the correct transform.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, bbgodfrey Thanks a lot. Your suggestion really helps me solve this problem.